# difference for WebSphere Application Server for Developers VS IBM WebSphere SDK Java 7 for Liberty and Full profile

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am downloading IBM WebSphere server for the developer edition. I find out two flavours (See attached picture)

1. WebSphere Application Server for Developers, Installation Manager Repository
2. IBM WebSphere SDK Java 7 for Liberty and Full profile, Installation Manager Repository

i am confused if these two are same. (or there is only the difference for the Java Version)

[image: Image Attached]

Answer (score 5):

Let me try to explain the differences. In that page you can download:

- IBM WebSphere Application Server for Developers, Full Profile (1-3) - this is developers version of the full Java EE 6 complaint WebSphere Application Server. It contains already Java SDK v6 and is ready to run.
- IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty for Developers - this is new lightweight, fast module based server. Directed for developers. Allows you to build your own server with specific features, compliant with Java EE 6 Web Profile. See more details here: [Introducing Liberty profile](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/introducing_the_liberty_profile/). In addition to Installation Manager download, you can just download zip archive, and just unpack it. It doesn't contain JDK, but  can be used with IBM or Oracle Java 6 or 7.
- IBM WebSphere SDK Java 7 for Liberty and Full profile - this is just the Java SDK. It can be used for both Full and Liberty profile. WAS 8.5.5 allows you to switch from Java 6 to Java 7. So you need this download, if you want to use Java 7 with Full profile.

If you are starting development, I'd suggest to download zip with Liberty and WebSphere Developer Tools from [wasdev](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/)

Comment: @AtulD You may accept the answer, if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this article in 2017](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/was-classic-or-was-liberty-how-to-choose/), there are some pros and cons choosing one over another

> ### General advice
>
> **Reasons to choose traditional WAS**
>
> - It costs nothing to move (if you’re already there and it does what you need)
> - Still has more function than Liberty
>
>   - Full API, full admin console, security options
>   - Some applications can’t move or would take too much effort
> - Uses existing admin skills and assets
>
>   - plus larger existing body of knowledge/information
>   - more training courses available
> - Integrated with more products for management/production
> - Common stack for key Portfolio products
> - Portal server, BPM
>
> **Reasons to choose Liberty**
>
> - Smaller, simpler, faster to set up
>
>   - easier to have common development and production runtimes
> - More flexible to install, update and manage
>
>   - packaged server ‘master image’ deployments are popular
> - Composable, right-sized runtimes
> - More choice of deployment environments
>
>   - Bluemix, other PaaS, containers
> - Liberty on z/OS has higher throughput, lower resource use
> - Servers of any edition can be centrally managed (although not clustered)
> - Greater management scale with collectives than cells
> - Earlier support of new technology through continuous delivery
> - Easier version to version migration once using Liberty